# C structs: segmentation fault

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault

Quick question about structs:

```
struct xint {
     int number;
     char string[12];
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct xint offsets, *poffsets;
  poffsets=&offsets;
  FILE * pFile = fopen("file","rb");
  fread(poffsets,1,16,pFile);
  printf("Number %d\nString %s\n",offsets.number,offsets.string);
}
```

I get this output

```
Number 12345
Segmentation fault
```

I know I've probably done something wrong with structures and pointers and memory allocation. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is you're directly reading into a struct from the file, without checking struct alignment. Do this instead:

```
  fread(&offset.number,1,sizeof(offsets.number),pFile);
  fread(&offset.string,1,sizeof(offsets.string),pFile);
```

Comment: printf would still bork on this if the string isn't 0-terminated.

Comment: ```&offset.string``` is redundant -- lose the ```&``` because ```offset.string``` is already a pointer to the buffer.

Comment: An alternative would also be to look at "#pragma pack", to ensure the structure is correctly aligned for an fread call for the whole structure...

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the file data you are reading does not terminate the string with a `NUL` (`'\0'`) character.  By the C definition of strings, which `printf()` of the C standard library abides, a string must be terminated with a `NUL` character.

You might be well-off to always (via code) ensure that `.string[11] = '\0'`.

OR, declare `string[13]` and ensure that `string[12] = '\0'`

Also, another poster mentioned struct member alignment concerns.  That is a valid concern you must also address.

Answer (score 0):

You get buffer overflow. Your string is made to contain 12 chars, but you don't have space for  a terminating `'\0'`.

If you did:

```
struct xint {
     int number;
     char string[16]; // Make sure you have enough space for the string + '\0'.
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct xint offsets, *poffsets;

    // Initialize your memory to 0. This will ensure your string is 
    // '\0'-terminated.
    // FYI, sizeof(xint) here is 20.
    memset(&offsets, 0, sizeof(xint)); 

    poffsets=&offsets;
    FILE * pFile = fopen("file","rb");
    fread(poffsets,1,16,pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
    printf("Number %d\nString %s\n",offsets.number,offsets.string);
}
```

That would fix the issue.

Comment: It would hide the issue. A 12 character string would still segfault (in the OP's code or 16 in this version).

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "it would hide the issue". This code works just fine. I've included the whole code so you get the idea. The concept of "allocate enough memory and ensure your string is '\0' terminated" is what counts in the current context, and my solution addresses this issue clearly IMO

Comment: Ah, the 16 was intentional. Thought it was a typo. Thing is that your struct size is now out of sync with your fread, which you'd normally code as `fread(poffsets, 1, sizeof(struct xint), pFile)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the string is not null-terminated in the file, and your code does nothing to null-terminate the string either.

```
fread(poffsets, 1, 16, pFile);
offsets.string[11] = '\0';
printf("Number %d\nString %s\n", offsets.number, offsets.string);
```

Or modify the file so the string ends with a null byte.

Comment: The \0 character is NUL, the pointer is NULL, otherwise strings are zero-terminated, not null-terminated.  Lowercase null means, literally, nothing -- as opposed to zero, which is something that represents nothing.  So a null-terminated string would be an unterminated string.  ;)  Have you read Alice in Wonderland or are you familiar with Magritte?  "This is not a pipe."

Comment: That solution would overwrite the last character of the string read.