# C Segmentation fault - saving struct in .dat file

Tags: c, pointers, fault

Can someone please tell me, what causes the segementation fault in my C - code? I am trying to save a struct into a file, and calling it afterwards, following [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/readwrite-structure-file-c/) guide. I don't see anything assigned wrongly, so I'm happy to learn what's my mistake by someone more experienced.

Here is my code, simplified:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *key = (argc > 4) ? argv[4]: 0;
    if(0==strcmp(key, "write")){
        struct MyStruct s;
        FILE *myoutfile;
        myoutfile = fopen("file.dat","w")
        if (myoutfile == NULL) 
        { 
                    fprintf(stderr, "\nError opend file\n"); 
                    exit (1); 
        } 
        s = get_struct(argv[2]);
        fwrite(&s, sizeof(struct MyStruct), 1, myoutfile);
        fclose(myoutfile);
    }else{
    struct MyStruct t;
    FILE *myinfile;
    myinfile = fopen("file.dat", "r")
    if (myinfile == NULL) 
    { 
                fprintf(stderr, "\nError opend file\n"); 
                exit (1); 
    } 
    while (fread(&t, sizeof(struct MyStruct), 1, myinfile))
        printf("Done reading");
    }
    work_with_struct(t);
    fclose(myinfile);
}
```

Also, as I read in [another stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5983089/c-structs-segmentation-fault), doing this:

```
fread(&t.one, sizeof(t.one), 1, myinfile);
fread(&t.two, sizeof(t.two), 1, myinfile);
fread(&t.three, sizeof(t.three), 1, myinfile);
```

did not work either.

**EDIT:** I now think i have located the problem a bit more. The first part of the function (if) works fine. What I thought was not necessary to mention first, was that in the end of the "else" I have a function that works with `t`. This is the one throwing the error, i believe.
It works fine, when I leave out the .dat-file-part, so by just saying

```
t = get_struct(argv[2]);
work_with_struct(t);
```

which I actually want to avoid, because "get_struct" is huge. Doing it once, and working with the data in the .dat file was my solution, that I calculate it only once.
My assumption now is, that putting the struct into the fstream and getting it back will somehow destroy it, or makes it somehow not-readable for `work_with_struct`. What I think is also worth mentioning is, that inside the struct there are three members: two char **, and one custom data type.
I didn't find any other solution suggesting other ways of reading in the file.

Maybe with this explanation someone gets alerted, where the segmentation fault might come from. Thanks a lot!

Comment: as it is, the example code does not even compile. Are you sure that this code is the code that produces a segfault? Is there code missing from the example?

Comment: @L.Grozinger My original code compiles, maybe i have made typo somewhere, when 'simplyfying the code for this post. Of course, functions like get_struct were not mentioned now. My code worked, before I tried to save the struct, that is why I only extracted the problematic part. In my case it will compile, I only get an error when running it.

Comment: it would be extremely useful to be able to compile and run your code under a debugger to identify where the segfault occurs. Have you tried that? Simply reading through a bunch of code and trying to guess where a segfault might occur is not easy...

Comment: There are many reasons for which the example code doesn't compile. The guide is also a bit iffy since the part  where they write "if(fwrite != 0)"  is always true.

Comment: Do you see, where the compiler has a problem? I'm afraid I can't give the function get_struct, because it again relys on other functions, but i can guarantee, it works, and it just returns some sort of structs. 
I hoped for a typical scheme where to search for the cause of the segmentation fault, because my compiler also does not give me more information than the fault itself.

Comment: @AleksanderBobiński I am open for improvement, like I sad, I just followed an (apparently not perfect) internet guide, because I haven't done something like this prior.

Comment: perhaps you should look into how to use a debugger, which will tell you where the segfault is coming from,  for example,  https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are passing a NULL pointer to strcmp which expects a const char*. When no arguments are passed to the program key = 0 and the program segfaults because strcmp attempts to dereference this NULL pointer.

Edit:
I attempted to correct the example program to make it compile and run, here it is:

Edit 2: print content of saved struct

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct MyStruct {
    int a;
};
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const char *key = (argc > 4) ? argv[4] : "write";
    if (0 == strcmp(key, "write")) {
            struct MyStruct s;
            FILE *myoutfile;
            myoutfile = fopen("file.dat", "w");
            if (myoutfile == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "\nError opend file\n");
                    exit(1);
            }
            s = (struct MyStruct){ 'a' };
            fwrite(&s, sizeof(struct MyStruct), 1, myoutfile);
            fclose(myoutfile);
    } else {
            struct MyStruct t;
            FILE *myinfile;
            myinfile = fopen("file.dat", "r");
            if (myinfile == NULL) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "\nError opend file\n");
                    exit(1);
            }
            while (fread(&t, sizeof(struct MyStruct), 1, myinfile))
                    printf("Done reading\n");
            printf("%c\n", t.a);
            fclose(myinfile);
    }
}
```

Edit 3:
After updating the description of the struct MyStruct the problem is obvious. You need to find a different way to save the struct to the file then by using fwrite since you have pointer types in it. The way you would go about that is a topic for a different question.

Comment: Could you please try to run it with write first, and then read in what is now saved in the file? Maybe then pass it into a function, that e.g. prints the members of the struct?
I just tried it again, and loading the struct with my get_struct() works, while writing in into the .dat and reading it back in causes the segmentation error. Is it the same for you? EDIT: I tried it again, and it works now, for whatever reason. Thank you!

Comment: EDIT2: My bad, it didn't work. The reason why I thought i would, was, because i left the get_struct() inside. So any additional ideas are very welcome.

Comment: Also, the function works well with kw "write", only reading has the error

Comment: @m4u_13n3 Printing the contents of a saved struct works fine. Maybe the issue is how you handle the struct returned from your get_struct() function. Could you edit the question and add it's signature?

Comment: @m4u_13n3 You should probably check out valgrind or try to compile with -fsanitize=address, it would make finding bugs in your code much easier.

Comment: What do you mean by adding its signature?

Comment: Function declarations are signatures. For example 'int f(int, int);' is a signature saying that you have a function that returns an int, is called "f" and takes two ints as parameters.

My guess is that somehow before the file is saved the contents of the struct get corrupted.

I do encourage you to try running the program with valgrind because at this point I'm guessing since the example works.

Comment: I now saw your edit about the pointer structure. Could you just give me some more hints, about how I can solve it (or keywords, that I can google)? It would be a huge help if this works somehow.

Comment: If you wish to **serialize** a POD struct in C then it's easy and the method in the guide will work. Your problem is more complex, its **serialization** of a struct with pointers. It needs a handcrafted solution. One idea is to write your own fwrite function that will save the struct and the things the pointers are pointing to. The thing is that this also means you have to write your own fread function. The other idea is to get rid of the pointers from the struct.

Comment: thanks! I have now created [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63171920/save-struct-with-pointer-members-in-file) to clarify my problem. I'm afraid it would not be easier to get rid of the pointers, as I'm only editing a open source project and am not familiar enough with it to change its whole structure.